# UIAlertView problem on device

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have the following code for the CLLocationManager delegate, when I test it on the simulator it worked just fine, but when I port it to my ipad I got a warning and the app freezes. Why is this?

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{


    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle: @"Pinging GPS"
                          message: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@, %@",newLocation.coordinate.latitude,newLocation.coordinate.longitude]
                          delegate: nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];

    NSString * newAudioFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"enter" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer * av = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:newAudioFile] error:NULL];
    [av play];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

}
```

The warning I got is:

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.1 (8G4)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found).
```

If I remove the UIAlertView, it works fine without that warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

latitude and longitude are doubles, not strings or such:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d, %d",newLocation.coordinate.latitude,newLocation.coordinate.longitude]
```

Comment: turns out the issue is that I have a stopMonitoringForRegion in a function, but yea thanks for pointing this out as well